# How to use Office.js in pre-existing React project

Tags: reactjs, office-js

I'm developing a Word Add-in app in my pre-existing React project.

I installed Office.js with the following command from [@microsoft/office-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/office-js).

```sh
npm i @microsoft/office-js
```

Now I'm trying to use the Office.js object like `Office.context.document.getFileAsync()` but I don't know how to import it and use it in the React project.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you load the Office JavaScript Library from the CDN with a `<script>` tag in the home page. See for exmaple the index.html and main.tsx files in this sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-GettingStartedFabricReact

If you want to use the library locally, you should be able to import it the same way you would import any other `@vendor/library.js` from the `node-modules` folder.